# Meaning of "se contentait"

Tags: sens, expressions

Context *"Le petit cochon se contentait de remuer sa grande marmite de soupe, et de rire. "*

If I'm  not mistaken "se contenter de" means 'to be satisfied with', but the translation of the text seems to translate it as "just/merely"

Comment: Yes, "just/merely" is a good equivalent in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se contenter de* does indeed mean "to be satisfied with" but it also [means by extension](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contenter) "to not do more than what one does".

So here, I would translate your sentence as

> The little pig *was satisfied to not do anything more than simply* stir his big pot of soup, and laugh

Comment: I'm not sure about the "satisfied" part. It seems to imply some degree of self-consciousness in the pig that doesn't really appear in the French sentence.

Comment: @guillaume31 That's true I guess, but I can't think of a translation that would not imply this.

Comment: "The little pig was *just* stirring his big pot of soup and laughing" ?

Comment: Or "The little pig was *simply* stirring his big pot of soup and laughing"